# Should I pull heavy wire through conduit to or from a bend at one end?

Tags: pull

I am going to be pulling 4/0 4/0 2/0 service wire in 2-1/2" conduit for 175ft. One end is at the meter coming up out of the ground though a 24" sweep and about 3ft of straight conduit on end. Meter is mounted on a 6x6 post. The other end is at the transformer and is straight with open trench on the last couple feet for access to pull wire. I would be able to pull straight out and up.

Seems to me, to be able to get a good pull on wire, that coming from the straight end at transformer would be the easiest. I would appreciate recommendations from anyone with experience doing similar pulls
Which direction should I pull from?
Thanks

Comment: Is there any elevation change between them? As a rule, pull downhill if there's a slope. You want gravity on your side.

Comment: @ecnerwal - maybe a foot or so over the 175ft. But I would have to pull up though the sweep to meter if I pull from meter side and meter is also on the higher side.

Comment: One way to have to pull 170+ feet of cable round a 90 degree bend, the  other way you only need to pull 4 or 5 feet  round the bend. do you have any mechanical assistance?

Comment: @jasen - No mechanical assistance, just muscle and lube. I understand what people are saying about not having to pull it all down the 24" sweep, but it also seems very hard to pull up 5ft though the 24" sweep. From the straight end I have ability to pull straight out and use multicable people if needed or hookup a come along or truck and pull if needed (last resort). Everyone seems to think it's a piece of cake pull. But, since I have never done one I am just using what I think is common sense

Comment: There is a reason code limits pulls to 360 degrees. Each bend increases the force on the wire by 360 mechanical means are often needed with large wires. Reducing the length of wire required to go through bend(s) is what pros do, yes we consider elevation but in this case it would need to be closer to a story before considering putting the entire length through a 90 there will be much more damage to the wires than only pulling 10’ through the 90.

Comment: Pulling manually from the meter can also be quite mechanically awkward, you're either pulling from shoulders up, or standing on a ladder (also pretty much also eliminating multiple human pullers). If pulling horizontal leaning gives you the advantage of body weight.

Comment: Is the conduit complete and reburied at the time you'll be pulling? I'm troubled by how there'll only be one 90, you'll be standing in a trench to pull from the flat end, and how you aren't prepared with proper pulling equipment (a come-along would be a good start; dragging a wire using a vehicle, bad plan unless it has a winch).  It suggests to me you plan to finish the conduit by sliding conduit sticks over the wires, a code violation for good reasons. And that you haven't buried and tamped the pipe (mistake).  It sounds like you are both shortcutting and underestimating.

Comment: I see both points of view. And seems like it's up for debate. I get it would be easier to push 10ft of cable though a 90, but I also see how it would be easier for the pusher to feed it downward in the conduit as someone else is pulling. I just don't know how easy it will be to pull up from the meter. And if I pull from the meter, I have to worry about getting dirt in conduit from dragging cable in the trench.

Comment: @harper-reinstate monica - conduit will be completely buried & packed as much as possible (trench is 30 to 36 in deep. End at the transformer will have open trench for about 2ft. The conduit will be stopped 2ft before edge of transformer so I can feed or pull wire easier. PUD will install the last couple feet of conduit and 24" sweep going into transformer. Conduit will be clamped to post at meter panel. Have not decided if I will have the panel in place or remove it during the pull. Seems meter maybe get damaged. After cable pulled, will feed though the panel knockout & complete install

Comment: You can't feed wires like that through an incomplete conduit. You have to finish the conduit first.  If *one end* is awaiting completion you can pull it up to there (you are allowed to assemble conduit around a pull rope).   However that leaves your cable flapping in the breeze ready to steal. *Mind you, those are NEC rules; the power company follows NESC. I doubt NESC is any different, but if the **power company** is telling you to do it that way, erm, ok then.*

Comment: @harper-reinstate monica - PUD will not allow me access to the transformer to feed completed conduit/wire into and since i am pulling wire on at Sat, they will not be there. I was told by they engineer and crew, leave the end open and conduit to complete into the transformer and they will do it. It's really the only option. I don't see why it would not be ok. It's no different then what you would have to do on a cable run with no conduit, at the end coming out of the ground. Slide it over, only difference is they will clue the outside of the smooth conduit, to connect to bell on end of my run.

Comment: @harper-reinstate monica - and even if i run conduit right up to the edge of their transformer, they still have to install the sweep into the transformer and then that leaves me no room to feed or pull wire

Comment: Sure, I get your frustration, it's a big project with a lot of moving parts... but know yourself.  You are a novice. Lots of novices succeed at projects like this, but not by shortcutting.  Not knowing the reasons for the rule is a *normal state of affairs* so it's no excuse to break rules. The problem is, when you start shortcutting because you don't know what you're doing and you're in a crunch, ***the pros notice***. And that backfires on you, complicating your world even further, and I'm guessing it doesn't need any more complications eh?

Comment: OK,so the meter pan will be installed complete before PUD comes to hook up their transformer, *right?*  Because - check with them but I'm pretty sure they mean "have the conduit compete on your end with meter pan installed, *and we'll hook up to the meter*."  And I wonder if they also mean "and they will pull".  Don't count on them being willing to sleeve conduit over wires; that's a codevio for them too most likely (I'm not an NESC expert).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Harper, this run is my responsibility. I run conduit, I run wire, I have my electrician hookup to the Meter box. After L&I gives approval, PUD comes and hooks up my wire to their transformer and puts in the meter to box. I am not taking any short cuts and taking this very seriously. Doing everything I can to make sure the pull goes smoothly. I spoke directly with engineer and the crew that was out hooking up their wire to the transformer. He told me just leave the sweep and they will feed it over wire and into transformer and complete conduit run.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I just got off the phone with the PUD engineer. He said it's not a problem at all to leave conduit short a couple feet, leave a stick of conduit with the sweep and they will dig out the last foot in-front/onside of transformer, install needed conduit with sweep over wire and clue, to complete run allowing it to feed into transformer. So, it clearly much be ok. Because they will not do the hookup until the whole installation, less that end is completed and inspected by L&I. Then they come out and do hookup with conduit and install Meter in panel.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Harper, we have talked on here about many electrical topics and I respect your opinion / views. Do you think I should pull wire toward the transformer, allowing someone to just push cable at meter post and pull from transformer side? Access just seems easier that way to pull. I get pulling all the wire though the 90 seems like more work, but I am using the lube you suggested and it will be easier to keep things lubed at that end as we feed cable into the 90 while one person push's and maybe two people pull.

Answer (score 4):

This is subjective I see opinions of folks that don’t do it often.

Pull the wire the to the bend so it will will be last with all other things being equal.

If you start the wire at the bend the entire pull has the 90 to pull through, if you pull the wire so the bend is at the end you only have the weight of the wire to deal with.

Make sure to have someone pushing (pulling wire off the spools) and pushing while the person at the other end is pulling this is an easy pull in ether direction but less resistance with the bend last.

Comment: I agree with your statement. But, would it really be affect from 170ft with someone pushing on wire from straight end to help get though the elbow, or is it just pure muscle to pull the last 10ft?

Comment: Dean, it makes a huge difference having someone to pull the wire off the spool, I use a tugger on big pulls think of a chain saw winch used outside but it is a full time gearbox to a gas motor and a capstan (I also have a 120v electric) I have snapped mule tape 2500 lb on 4 wire pull 4/0 with 3 90’s because my apprentice did not believe him pushing the wire made that big a difference, we had to pull back and I went to get 5k rope and he told me that he was not helping. We pulled it in the second time without even dropping into low gear all he was doing was spinning the spools & applying lube.

Comment: And think of the forces that is creating on the conduit pipe!  Another reason conduit needs to be backfilled and tamped.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I completely understand, but I do not have a winch. I do have a come along, but nothing to mount it to, to pull straight up from 24" sweep side, which is why I am leaning to pull the other directly. so someone can push the cable down, while someone pulls. I am getting all stressed out over this and this forum is just confusing me more. Everyone has been telling me how easy of a pull this will be, but you guys are making it sound like a very hard pull regardless of what direction I pull. Seems like a 50/50 split of what everyone things is the best direction to pull.

Comment: Dean this pull will be heavy think of the weight dragging on the ground. This is not a hard pull. I would use pull soap or lube, A quart will be plenty and will make the job easier. You only need to lube the first 1/2 after ~80’ no more lube is needed the pipe has enough. A second person pulling the wire off the spools and applying lube makes this A easy pull because of the single 90, the question is the direction, I highly recommend a helper OR you may end up running to the spools to unwind then going to the other end to pull many times. Lube is not required but it helps reduce friction/ wear

Answer (score 3):

I would feed at the elbow, less likely for 6 feet of rope to cut into the conduit elbow.

I always use a little pulling lube. It shouldn't take much, most of the friction will be at the elbow. If pulling toward the meter and the lube drags off it's hard to add lube for the last 6', but if pushing into the meter and it starts to drag it's easy to add lube
to the friction point.

Pushing into meter it is less likely for the lube to pick up debris from the trench going into conduit and (selfishly) less cleaning of the wire for termination in the meter. You should at least wipe down the utility end, but they will likely just trim off the worst part of it.

If the pull gets tough the helper pushing into the elbow is quite effective, pushing into a conduit not fixed in place, 170' away, might not prove to be much help.

Comment: It is always easier to pull with someone taking the wire off the spools even small 12 awg is much easier. A “pusher” also reduces the damage to the outer jacket that is there to make the pull easier and protect the actual insulation.

Comment: Agree it's easier, I was actually assuming an amateur shouldn't even try to pull it in alone. Anybody who does this for a living and is familiar with nuances (and had to overcome mistakes) could pretty easily find a good layout to do it alone, but lacking experience he needs eyes on both ends.

Comment: of course I am going to have help.

Comment: @Dean No offense was intended, just drawing a distinction.

Answer (score 1):

I would feed from the elbow end, assuming you have a helper.  Wire that thick is stiff, and then pushing the wire down the elbow a few feet away would be loads easier than pulling through the elbow with 200’ of cable dragging.

And, always use lube.

Comment: So you think forcing 3 heavy wires through a 90 for 170+ feet is easier than only having to pull them through a 90 for ~10’ interesting. It looks like someone else agrees that has not pulled much cable.

Answer (score 1):

The question is subjective and probably depends on the nuances of your situation. Here's some general advice. You decide.

Benefits of feeding from the end with the elbow:

- An assistant can help push past the elbow and bend the wire.
- The pull is much easier for the remaining distance.
- You don't have to get through the elbow *while* dragging the wire all the way.

Benefits of feeding from the straight end:

- It's easy sailing most of the way.
- You'd only need to pull a short length beyond the elbow.
- There will be less wear on the conduit from the pull string.

Comment: Is it really that hard to pull though one 24” sweep in either direction? This triplex seems to want to coil with a nice Radius naturally. And if someone is pushed from a few feet above it just seems like it would flow so easy. But yes I know I don’t have experience. But I do have common sense

Comment: Dean the 90 is not the problem at all it is the 170’ that is a fair amount of weight ~350 lbs if I did the math right sure it can be pulled not a problem but a second person, lube and direction of pull all make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ed Beal's pulling advice is as good as advice gets.

The electrician promised to *hook up* the meter, that was not the same as telling you to pull the wire before the meter is *installed* and then thread the wires through the meter KO.  No electrician would say that.   I would definitely install the meter before pulling wire, because not doing so is a blatant code violation.

I realize that's a complication you may not have figured for, but that's why being your own GC is hard.

Expecting the electrician to thread the wires through the KO would not be a thing I would do, unless the electrican told me to.  You are just begging for a much bigger complication than you have now.  It's hard enough *finding* an electrician willing to follow behind a DIYer and "turn the last bolts".  Don't give them reasons to doubt the arrangement.

It is more difficult to guide the wires around the meter pan contents, but not *that much* more difficult - the wire needs to be guarded and guided anyway on the feeding end, or pull forces will greatly increase as Ed says.

As far as which direction to pull, you need to have a plan and the necessary equipment, *and you need to know you have it*.  So I will actually go against Ed's advice for several reasons, and advise feeding at the meter and pulling from the flat end.  The difficulty is greater *but that's my point*: the job will *start hard* and get *slightly* harder as it progresses, **so you will sooner know if you need more help**. The other direction is easy most of the run, and the last 6’ is like hitting a wall - suddenly quite hard.  Again this advice is for a first time puller; Ed certainly doesn't need it!

Also, since I am advising pulling through an installed meter pan, it's easier to guide in loose wires than pull a taut line.

Also, I would ordinarily want the pull rope to be on the end with the unfinished conduit; it's perfectly legal to assemble conduit over a pull rope :) I would only pull the cable through as the power company instructed *because* they instructed that.

But I maybe wouldn't do it until after the inspector came and went.  Last thing you need is to be caught in the crossfire of a jurisdictional squabble between inspector and Utility.

Also keep in mind site security.  Aluminum is cheap*er*, but it's still worth some money.  Don't want to have the power company calling and saying "where's the wire" or "why'd you pull it too far" when vandals or thieves did that.

Comment: monica-Meter box will be there and wires will be pulled though the KO. I am talking about the Meter reader that PUD installs. I am completely following code and being advised by certified electricians. I talk to you guys because I like to educate myself and make sure things are being done right. No corners are being cut. I am using quality products and doing it per code. I am doing everything except attachment of the wires to the boxes panels, and only so I can say a certified electrician did it. I could do it as well & from some of the workmanship I have seen, likely better.

Comment: monica - As for as leaving the conduit short. I don't understand how I am suppose to complete a run of conduit with wires, when I have to first install the conduit, bury it and then pull wire and i can't complete the conduit until I install the wire. Are you following me? I cannot get into the PUD box to complete the run, they have to do it. So, my guess is that L&I has an agreement with PUD that this is the way of business in my county, since in my county this part of the wire run is my responsibility, less the hookups to transformer.

Comment: reinstate Monica - Harper, you your self told me this would be a easy pull in a previous conversation on here. You told me to just use some old rope. I am using 3/4 mule tape. No mention of needing any special equipment.  I have a plan and from talking to you and others, I have been told it would be no problem by hand, you stated just wear some thick gloves. So, please don't bust my balls over how I am handling this install. I am going to bring a come along just in case i need it.

Comment: @Dean I'm not trying to, you asked me how I'd do it above, and I'm saying.   It sounds to me like you've done your diligence on this and are deviating from NEC because your power company told you to.  That works for me.  Can't say whether it works for your inspector.  I am sure I never said gloved hands would suffice or that it would be easy.  Must be someone else.

Comment: I think Ed's advice is good as well, but I also have the other half of this group telling me to pull the other way. I have no idea who is the more experienced with this.

Comment: @Dean Ed Beal, no question.

Comment: Harper - Reinstate Monica -Harper & Ed. Are you telling me I cannot do this pull by hand with the lube you recommended with 3 strong men, regardless of what direction I go? What should I use besides muscles? I am sorry for being upset, but I thought I had a plan and could do it. Now I am being told other wise

Comment: Harper - Reinstate Monica- It was Ed that said gloves in the post about mule tape. sorry Harper. You said any old rope would work and Poly Lube

Comment: harp, you also said if things get hot and heavy use a come along

Comment: i just need to know if I can do this? I am a very capable person and will have a big strong son in law to help, with the girls put on the lube. I can get one or two more guys if I need them, but it's hard to find people to commit

Comment: I think you should be alright, since if all else fails, you have the come-along.  More of the work than you think is guiding the wires in, like Ed says. I just really wanted to make sure the details are right.  There are a lot of em.

Comment: Harper - Reinstate Monica - Ed beal - I am picking up an electric 1500lb wrench with hitch mounting bracket as a back up. I feel better about it already. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

There's some things to consider about putting wires into conduits.

1: you can't push a wire through a conduit that's longer than the "stiffness length" of the wire.  when you push a wire it tends to bunch up. when you pull a wire it straightens out.

2: Bends are a force multiplier they multiply the force needed to pull the wire to the bend by some number

3: lube will reduce the multiplication you get from the bend and
the force needed to pull it along the straights

Now your situation:

You have a long horizontal run and a short vertical run.

If you feed the wires from the vertical (meter) end they fall by gravity to the bend so it's mostly multiplying zero by something but you need someone to keep feeding else the friction rapidly increases.  A guide or slipper at the feed end may help in feeding the wires as you need to prevent them from getting badly scratched.  Pulling horizontally on the ground is much easier than pulling vertically in the air.

Wear gloves when feeding to avoid getting pinched if it suddenly hits an easy spot (or passes a hard spot).

The feeder will need to lift every foot of wire to the height of the inlet and feed it in.  If you can support the spool on an elevated axle with will help their task.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My plan is to feed from the meter. I will have my 6'4 strong son in law doing the feeding and my daughter adding lube as it goes in. On pulling end it was going to be me and a neighbor, but I just got a 1500 lb wench and hitch mount. So now the plan is to hookup wench and slowly pull. I made a pull head, peeled back covering about 1 1/2 ft back and folded the wires back, staggering them some. Seems to be no more thicker then the 3 wires I am pulling. When i get up to do pull, I will attach pull line and tape the shit out of it to keep it in place.

Comment: @jason -  I know everyone says not to do this, but I am going to pull the meter/breaker panel combo during the pull just to give room to feed and prevent damage. Everything will in installed complete, conduit clamped to post in two places as it come out of the ground. I am just going to unbolt the panel from mounting rails on post. After wire is pulled, I will leave a few feet to feed though the KO in panel and reinstall panel complete.

Comment: They  say not to because it's a code violation

Comment: @jason - why is that. If nothing else is hooked up and it's just to position the conduit coming out of the ground and all the hookups will be done after wire pulled. I don't understand why you would want to pull wire though a KO, especially large wires. Besides being a code, is it really an issue?

Comment: @jason - I want to do things to code. So, I guess I will leave the panel in place. It would be easier to feed wire straight down, a couple feet about without the panel there. If all is clamped and clued, all that needs connect is the KO fitting nut and cap, this rule make no sense.

Comment: code says that wire should be pulled with the junction boxes and all conduit in place. for a professional with a winch this is less of a problem than for a DIYer doing it by hand.  I think the reason is to prevent the construction of unservicable cable runs.

Comment: @jason - I will be using a wench on the pulling side and feeding from the meter. As you stated, just making sure the cable is above a foot or more as it is being feed to prevent damage to cable and make it feed easier.

Comment: Is that a typo?

Comment: @jason - lol, yes